# /bin/sh: 1: touch not found

Tags: java, sh

What could be the problem with the code below, when passed with `command = touch aaa`

it throws `/bin/sh: 1: touch aaa: not found`

Here's the code

```
boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name")
        .toLowerCase().startsWith("windows");
String [] cmd ={"-c", command};
CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("/bin/sh");
cmdLine.addArguments( cmd,false );
if (isWindows) {
    DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
    exec.setExitValue(0);
    exec.setWorkingDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    int exitCode = exec.execute(cmdLine);
    return new Response(exitCode, "");

} else {
    DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
    exec.setExitValue(0);
    exec.setWorkingDirectory(new File(System.getenv("HOME")));
    int exitCode = exec.execute(cmdLine);
    return new Response(exitCode, "");
}
```

Comment: No idea - but you shouldn't need to `/bin/sh -c` your commands. It's often not needed to exec a tool and tell it to exec some commands when you can directly exec them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a proper space (0x20) between `touch` and `aaa`?

When you try to run a non-existent command from `sh` with a parameter, the 'not found' message from the shell does not include the parameter:

```
% sh -c 'touchx aaa'        
sh: 1: touchx: not found
% dash -c 'touchx aaa'      
dash: 1: touchx: not found
% bash -c 'touchx aaa'
bash: touchx: command not found
% busybox sh -c 'touchx aaa'
sh: touchx: not found
```

Try to run your command from the command line, without the Java code, and see if it works from there.